# How do template literals work in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm just curious as to how JS handles expressions inside template literals.
On one hand,

```
console.log(`hi ${3>5}`); //false
```

meaning the logical expression is indeed evaluated, and

```
function myFunction()
{
      return("caca");
};

console.log(`${myFunction()}`);`
```

actually produces the desired "caca" meaning the function is executed just like the previous logical expression was evaluated, but

```
console.log (`${function() {return("caca");}}`); //returns function() {return("caca");}
```

does not.
I know that marking the function expression as self-executing will actually run it, but I just wonder why the JS engine behaves this way. I know the JS engine doesn't care about my "intuition" but I intuitively assumed the function expression inside the template literal would be executed.

Comment: `myFunction()` executes `myFunction` and returns the value to the caller. `function() {return("caca");}` only defines a function but does not execute it. If you want to see similar results, try `console.log(\`${myfunction}\`)`

Comment: What your mean is probably: ```console.log (`${(function() {return("caca");})()}`);``` ... so its actually invking the function instead of just defining it.

Comment: In the first example you're calling the function, in the latter you're just passing a reference (the anonymous function) to `console.log`, why would a reference be executed without invoking it? Notice, that in the second example the console logs the same as what it would log without the template, the logged value in the example is not the string template literal creates.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you were to evaluate the code inside the template literal that "doesn't work", you aren't actually *running* the function. Take, for example, this code:

```
function myFunction()
{
      return("caca");
};
```

On its own, this is a function, not the string `"caca"`. Only when you run the function does it return that value. In your template literal, you are just defining an anonymous function. To run it, you would need to do this:

```
console.log (`${(function() {return("caca");})()}`);
```

This runs the function after defining it, and logs the function's return value.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now what was conceptually wrong in my understanding of this. I had some issues understanding the difference between defining the function and running it.

Comment: @geeheeb You're welcome. You also don't need the parentheses around `return`, which saves some typing (`return "caca"`)